# Azure Blob how to properly create and consume a SAS token

Tags: c#, azure

Before I begin, allow me to say that I have scoured MSFTs docs, everything seems to imply that I need to manually handroll the GET request? Which seems wrong, given that the SDK handles that for us.

What I am experiencing from my Xamarin app is the following 403 error when I try to run my code to get a list of blobs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.</Message></Error>
```

The way my workflow goes is as follows:

- App Makes request to API to get Azure SAS token
- API Responds using the following code to return the SAS token (blobServiceClient is defined using the default emulator storage connection string):

  try
  {
  var client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(request.VenueId);
  var permissions = BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read | BlobContainerSasPermissions.List;
  var sas = client.GenerateSasUri(permissions, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(1));

  ```
               var containerUri = "";

               #if DEBUG
                               var temp = sas.AbsoluteUri;
                               var replaced = temp.Replace("http://127.0.0.1:10000/", "http://myngrokproxy.ngrok.io/");
                               containerUri = replaced;
               #else
                               containerUri = sas.AbsoluteUri;
               #endif

               //var sas = containerUri + container.GetSharedAccessSignature(accessPolicy);

               return new AzureSASResponse
               {
                   SAS = containerUri
               };

           } catch (Exception e)
           {
               return null;
           }
  ```

As you can see, the replace is there since localhost URL is meaningless for the emulator.

- App side I try to consume it as follows:

  ```
            try
            {
               var uri = new Uri(SAS);
               var containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(uri);
               var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs().AsPages();

               foreach(var blob in blobs)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(blob);
               }

           } catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }
  ```

My resulting SAS token looks like so: `"http://myngrokproxy.ngrok.io/devstoreaccount1/8dc9e4831d634629b386680ad7c9a324?sv=2020-08-04&se=2021-10-21T21%3A43%3A16Z&sr=c&sp=rl&sig=oncjUlSLMsOS3WbxUWqjXDp28WACYxxVqUElrK%2BYNlY%3D"`

How can I go about A) setting the auth header on it, even the GET request that fails is the .GetBlobs method in the Xamarin app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error my ways to fix it were as follows:

1. Use latest version of azurite from Microsoft, I used the original old one (Arafuto/azurite)
2. change code to look as follows;

   ```
    var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
                {
                    BlobContainerName = containerClient.Name,
                    Resource = "c",
                    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                };

                sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.List);

                var client = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(request.VenueId);
                var permissions = BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read | BlobContainerSasPermissions.List;
                var sas = client.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);

                var containerUri = "";

   #if DEBUG
                var temp = sas.AbsoluteUri;
                var replaced = temp.Replace("http://127.0.0.1:10000/", "http://myngrokproxy.ngrok.io/");
                containerUri = replaced;
   #else
                containerUri = sas.AbsoluteUri;
   #endif


                return new AzureSASResponse
                {
                    SAS = containerUri
                };
   ```

The inspiration for the BlobSasBuilder came from this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet#get-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-container